# How to create a new sprint in JIRA programmatically?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I'm migrating a number of projects from one JIRA instance to another using JSON importer. Although the importer can assign issues to existing sprints, the sprints themselves must already exist -- a [limitation of the current version of JIRA Importer](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/JIM-1091).

We've been creating sprints by hand 'till now, but some of our projects have a large number of them, which make the manual process both tedious and error-prone.

It does not appear like JIRA REST API can create new sprints either -- although people talk about the greenhopper/1.0/sprint/create endpoint, it does not exist.

Is there, perhaps, some other way to create sprints programmatically? I have no problems with obtaining the full list of them from the source JIRA instance, it is creating them in the target instance, that does not seem possible...

Any hope? Can I INSERT new records into the AO_60DB71_SPRINT-table with a SQL-client? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of JIRA and JIRA Agile are you using? And what does Chrome Developer Tools show being called in the Network tab when you create a sprint in the browser?

Comment: JIRA 6.1.7, JIRA Agile 6.3.12. What is "Chrome Developer Tools"? Is that a JIRA plugin?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the JIRA Agile API. See [JIRA Agile REST API Reference](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/7.0.4/#agile/1.0/)

So, for example using `curl`:

```
## Request JIRA Sprint POST Create
curl -X "POST" "https://jira.foobar.com/rest/agile/1.0/sprint" \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -u 'myusername:mypassword' \
     -d $'{
  "startDate": "2018-04-23T00:00:00.000+01:00",
  "name": "Cool Sprint",
  "endDate": "2018-05-03T13:00:00.000+01:00",
  "originBoardId": 1072
}'
```

The response of which would be:

```
{
  "id": 1130,
  "self": "https://jira.foobar.com/rest/agile/1.0/sprint/1130",
  "state": "future",
  "name": ""Cool Sprint",
  "startDate": "2018-04-23T01:00:00.000+02:00",
  "endDate": "2018-05-03T14:00:00.000+02:00",
  "originBoardId": 1072
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've changed jobs since posting this question and so am unable to verify your answer myself. But, if somebody else confirms it, I'll be happy to "accept " it.

Comment: Confirm that answer is good. values of `name` and `originBoardId` are mandatory.
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/8.9.0/#agile/1.0/sprint